# adding text in a shape

Tags: html, css

How do I not only keep this text centered but have the parallelogram border wrap around h1? I'm still very new to web design....I started with adding the shape I needed, making the color the same as the background, and simply adding the border.  But applying it to h1 screws up the entire layout! (not centered)  Also I haven't tinkered with it's sizing because it doesn't sit on the page correctly.

```css
:root {
    background: #dcd0ff;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Sacramento';font-size: 45px;text-align: center;
}
#shape1{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: skew(20deg);
  background: #dcd0ff;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="shape1">
  Sarra's Homemade Kombucha!
</h1>
```

Comment: You probably need `text-align: left` for `h1` style.

Answer (score 0):

You had some css syntax errors. And it's best practice to wrap text with a tag (I used `<span>`) in the below example.

EDIT: set margin-right/left to auto to center the h1. More info on margin alignment here ------> [CSS Margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp).

And @dvfleet413 is right as well. You should really use a div for something like this (containers and such) and then put your h1 inside that div.

The JavaScript is not needed. This is just a test template I always use. Will remove

Comments added.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      root {
    background: #dcd0ff;
}
/* you were missing a closing bracket here*/
div {
    font-family: 'Sacramento';font-size: 45px;text-align: center;
    }
#shape1 {
    /*only set width on container*/
width: 40%;
        padding: 30px;
      transform: skew(20deg);
      background: #dcd0ff;
      border: 1px black solid;

      /*set margin-left/right to auto to center*/
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
    }
    #shape1 span {
        /*set height/width of span*/
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="shape1">
   <span>Sarra's Homemade Kombucha!</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!  I saw you added javascript also...Why is that?

Comment: Also-Any way to center this?  And is there any way I can simply choose where to put the shape within the same line without effecting h1?

Comment: That makes sense! If it is a container the text align would be for within the container not the object itself!  Thank you!

Comment: Yep, exactly. No problem. If you feel this answered the question you can mark this as answered. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
:root {
    background: #dcd0ff;
}

#shape1 {
      width: 150px;
      height: 100px;
      transform: skew(20deg);
      background: #dcd0ff;
      border: 1px black solid;
      text-align: center;
    }

h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}
</style>
<div id="shape1">
    <h1>Sarra's Homemade Kombucha!</h1>
</div>
```

Here's how I would do it. I find it easier to use `<div>`'s when dealing with shapes like this.  They're meant to be containers for other elements, which is exactly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks for the response!